# ImportError phonenumbers with google cloud dataflow python

Tags: python, import, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, importerror

I am trying to do a relatively simple import of the module phonenumbers in Python.

I have tested the module on a seperate python file without any other imports and it works completely fine.

These are the packages I have installed:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function

import argparse
import csv
import logging
import os
import phonenumbers

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
```

And this is is my error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clean.py", line 114, in <module>
    run()
  File "clean.py", line 109, in run
    | 'WriteOutputText' >> beam.io.WriteToText(known_args.output))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\pipeline.py", line 389, in __exit__
    self.run().wait_until_finish()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\runners\dataflow\dataflow_runner.py", line 996, in wait_until_finish
    (self.state, getattr(self._runner, 'last_error_msg', None)), self)
apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner.DataflowRuntimeException: Dataflow pipeline failed. State: FAILED, Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 733, in run
    self._load_main_session(self.local_staging_directory)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 472, in _load_main_session
    pickler.load_session(session_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 247, in load_session
    return dill.load_session(file_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py", line 363, in load_session
    module = unpickler.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1139, in load_reduce
    value = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py", line 766, in _import_module
    return __import__(import_name)
ImportError: No module named phonenumbers
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT : I have already installed phonenumbers with pip

```
$ pip install phonenumbers
Requirement already satisfied: phonenumbers in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (8.9.7)
gax-google-logging-v2 0.8.3 has requirement google-gax<0.13.0,>=0.12.5, but you'll have google-gax 0.15.16 which is incompatible.
gcloud 0.18.3 has requirement google-gax<0.13dev,>=0.12.3, but you'll have google-gax 0.15.16 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-vision 0.29.0 has requirement requests<3.0dev,>=2.18.4, but you'll have requests 2.18.2 which is incompatible.
gax-google-pubsub-v1 0.8.3 has requirement google-gax<0.13.0,>=0.12.5, but you'll have google-gax 0.15.16 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-spanner 0.29.0 has requirement requests<3.0dev,>=2.18.4, but you'll have requests 2.18.2 which is incompatible.
```

This is the pip freeze output

```
$ pip freeze
adal==1.0.1
apache-beam==2.4.0
asn1crypto==0.22.0
avro==1.8.2
azure==3.0.0
azure-batch==4.1.3
azure-common==1.1.12
azure-cosmosdb-nspkg==2.0.2
azure-cosmosdb-table==1.0.3
azure-datalake-store==0.0.22
azure-eventgrid==0.1.0
azure-graphrbac==0.40.0
azure-keyvault==0.3.7
azure-mgmt==2.0.0
azure-mgmt-advisor==1.0.1
azure-mgmt-applicationinsights==0.1.1
azure-mgmt-authorization==0.30.0
azure-mgmt-batch==5.0.1
azure-mgmt-batchai==0.2.0
azure-mgmt-billing==0.1.0
azure-mgmt-cdn==2.0.0
azure-mgmt-cognitiveservices==2.0.0
azure-mgmt-commerce==1.0.1
azure-mgmt-compute==3.0.1
azure-mgmt-consumption==2.0.0
azure-mgmt-containerinstance==0.3.1
azure-mgmt-containerregistry==1.0.1
azure-mgmt-containerservice==3.0.1
azure-mgmt-cosmosdb==0.3.1
azure-mgmt-datafactory==0.4.0
azure-mgmt-datalake-analytics==0.3.0
azure-mgmt-datalake-nspkg==2.0.0
azure-mgmt-datalake-store==0.3.0
azure-mgmt-devtestlabs==2.2.0
azure-mgmt-dns==1.2.0
azure-mgmt-eventgrid==0.4.0
azure-mgmt-eventhub==1.2.0
azure-mgmt-hanaonazure==0.1.1
azure-mgmt-iothub==0.4.0
azure-mgmt-iothubprovisioningservices==0.1.0
azure-mgmt-keyvault==0.40.0
azure-mgmt-loganalytics==0.1.0
azure-mgmt-logic==2.1.0
azure-mgmt-machinelearningcompute==0.4.1
azure-mgmt-managementpartner==0.1.0
azure-mgmt-marketplaceordering==0.1.0
azure-mgmt-media==0.2.0
azure-mgmt-monitor==0.4.0
azure-mgmt-msi==0.1.0
azure-mgmt-network==1.7.1
azure-mgmt-notificationhubs==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-nspkg==2.0.0
azure-mgmt-powerbiembedded==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-rdbms==0.1.0
azure-mgmt-recoveryservices==0.2.0
azure-mgmt-recoveryservicesbackup==0.1.1
azure-mgmt-redis==5.0.0
azure-mgmt-relay==0.1.0
azure-mgmt-reservations==0.1.0
azure-mgmt-resource==1.2.2
azure-mgmt-scheduler==1.1.3
azure-mgmt-search==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-servermanager==1.2.0
azure-mgmt-servicebus==0.4.0
azure-mgmt-servicefabric==0.1.0
azure-mgmt-sql==0.8.6
azure-mgmt-storage==1.5.0
azure-mgmt-subscription==0.1.0
azure-mgmt-trafficmanager==0.40.0
azure-mgmt-web==0.34.1
azure-nspkg==2.0.0
azure-servicebus==0.21.1
azure-servicefabric==6.1.2.9
azure-servicemanagement-legacy==0.20.6
azure-storage-blob==1.1.0
azure-storage-common==1.1.0
azure-storage-file==1.1.0
azure-storage-nspkg==3.0.0
azure-storage-queue==1.1.0
CacheControl==0.12.5
cachetools==2.1.0
certifi==2017.7.27.1
cffi==1.10.0
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
configparser==3.5.0
crcmod==1.7
cryptography==2.0.3
deprecation==2.0.3
dill==0.2.6
docopt==0.6.2
entrypoints==0.2.3
enum34==1.1.6
fasteners==0.14.1
firebase-admin==2.11.0
Flask==0.12.2
funcsigs==1.0.2
future==0.16.0
futures==3.2.0
gapic-google-cloud-datastore-v1==0.15.3
gapic-google-cloud-error-reporting-v1beta1==0.15.3
gapic-google-cloud-logging-v2==0.91.3
gapic-google-cloud-pubsub-v1==0.15.4
gax-google-logging-v2==0.8.3
gax-google-pubsub-v1==0.8.3
gcloud==0.18.3
google-api-core==0.1.4
google-apitools==0.5.20
google-auth==1.5.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
google-auth-oauthlib==0.2.0
google-cloud==0.33.1
google-cloud-bigquery==0.28.0
google-cloud-bigquery-datatransfer==0.1.1
google-cloud-bigtable==0.28.1
google-cloud-container==0.1.1
google-cloud-core==0.28.1
google-cloud-dataflow==2.4.0
google-cloud-datastore==1.4.0
google-cloud-dns==0.28.0
google-cloud-error-reporting==0.28.0
google-cloud-firestore==0.28.0
google-cloud-language==1.0.2
google-cloud-logging==1.4.0
google-cloud-monitoring==0.28.1
google-cloud-pubsub==0.30.1
google-cloud-resource-manager==0.28.1
google-cloud-runtimeconfig==0.28.1
google-cloud-spanner==0.29.0
google-cloud-speech==0.30.0
google-cloud-storage==1.6.0
google-cloud-trace==0.17.0
google-cloud-translate==1.3.1
google-cloud-videointelligence==1.0.1
google-cloud-vision==0.29.0
google-gax==0.15.16
google-resumable-media==0.3.1
googleapis-common-protos==1.5.3
googledatastore==7.0.1
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.11.4
grpc-google-logging-v2==0.8.1
grpc-google-pubsub-v1==0.8.1
grpcio==1.12.0
gunicorn==19.7.1
hdfs==2.1.0
httplib2==0.9.2
idna==2.5
ipaddress==1.0.18
iso8601==0.1.12
isodate==0.6.0
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.9.6
jmespath==0.9.3
keyring==12.2.1
keystoneauth1==3.8.0
linecache2==1.0.0
MarkupSafe==1.0
mock==2.0.0
monotonic==1.5
msgpack==0.5.6
msrest==0.5.0
msrestazure==0.4.32
ndg-httpsclient==0.4.2
nelson==0.4.0
oauth2client==3.0.0
oauthlib==2.1.0
os-service-types==1.2.0
packaging==17.1
pathlib2==2.3.2
pbr==4.0.3
phonenumbers==8.9.7
ply==3.8
proto-google-cloud-datastore-v1==0.90.4
proto-google-cloud-error-reporting-v1beta1==0.15.3
proto-google-cloud-logging-v2==0.91.3
proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1==0.15.4
protobuf==3.5.2.post1
psutil==5.4.6
psycopg2==2.7.3.2
pyasn1==0.4.3
pyasn1-modules==0.2.1
pycparser==2.18
pyjwt==1.5.0
pyOpenSSL==17.2.0
pyparsing==2.2.0
pyreadline==2.1
python-dateutil==2.7.3
pytz==2018.3
PyVCF==0.6.8
pywin32-ctypes==0.1.2
PyYAML==3.12
rackspaceauth==0.2.0
requests==2.18.2
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
requests-toolbelt==0.8.0
rsa==3.4.2
scandir==1.7
six==1.10.0
SQLAlchemy==1.1.14
stevedore==1.28.0
traceback2==1.4.0
twilio==6.5.0
typing==3.6.4
unittest2==1.1.0
urllib3==1.22
virtualenv==16.0.0
Werkzeug==0.12.2
```

EDIT: Code ==

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function

import argparse
import csv
import logging
import os
from collections import OrderedDict
import phonenumbers

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions


class ParseCSVFn(beam.DoFn):
    """Parses the raw CSV data into a Python dictionary."""

    def process(self, elem):
        try:
            row = list(csv.reader([elem]))[0]
            month, day, year = row[2].split('/')
            birth_dict = {
                'day': day,
                'month': month,
                'year': year,
            }
            order_dict = OrderedDict(birth_dict)
            data_dict = {
                'phoneNumber': row[4],
                'firstName': row[0],
                'lastName': row[1],
                'birthDate': order_dict,
                'voterId': row[3],
            }

            order_data_dict = OrderedDict(data_dict)

            yield order_data_dict

        except:

            pass


def run(argv=None):
    """Pipeline entry point, runs the all the necessary processes"""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--input',
                        type=str,
                        dest='input',
                        default='gs://wordcount_project/demo-contacts-small*.csv',
                        help='Input file to process.')
    parser.add_argument('--output',
                        dest='output',
                        # CHANGE 1/5: The Google Cloud Storage path is required
                        # for outputting the results.
                        default='gs://wordcount_project/cleaned.csv',
                        help='Output file to write results to.')

    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    pipeline_args.extend([
        # CHANGE 2/5: (OPTIONAL) Change this to DataflowRunner to
        # run your pipeline on the Google Cloud Dataflow Service.
        '--runner=DataflowRunner',
        # CHANGE 3/5: Your project ID is required in order to run your pipeline on
        # the Google Cloud Dataflow Service.
        '--project=--------',
        # CHANGE 4/5: Your Google Cloud Storage path is required for staging local
        # files.
        # '--dataset=game_dataset',
        '--staging_location=gs://wordcount_project/staging',
        # CHANGE 5/5: Your Google Cloud Storage path is required for temporary
        # files.
        '--temp_location=gs://wordcount_project/temp',
        '--job_name=cleaning-jobs',
    ])

    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)

    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        (p
         | 'ReadInputText' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(known_args.input)
         | 'ParseDataFn' >> beam.ParDo(ParseCSVFn())
         # | 'JsonBirthDay' >> beam.ParDo(JsonBirthDay())
         # | 'MatchNumber' >> beam.ParDo(MatchNumber('phoneNumber'))
         # | 'MapData' >> beam.Map(lambda elem: (elem['phoneNumber'], elem['firstName'], elem['lastName'],
         #                                       elem['birthDate'], elem['voterId']))
         | 'WriteOutputText' >> beam.io.WriteToText(known_args.output))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

I have also tried to install specific packages of google-gax and requests but it didn't seem to help

EDIT: new coding error:

```
  File "new_clean.py", line 226, in <module>
    run()
  File "new_clean.py", line 219, in run
    | 'WriteToText' >> beam.io.WriteToText(known_args.output)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\pipeline.py", line 389, in __exit__
    self.run().wait_until_finish()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\pipeline.py", line 369, in run
    self.to_runner_api(), self.runner, self._options).run(False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\pipeline.py", line 382, in run
    return self.runner.run_pipeline(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\runners\dataflow\dataflow_runner.py", line 324, in run_pipeline
    self.dataflow_client.create_job(self.job), self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\utils\retry.py", line 180, in wrapper
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\runners\dataflow\internal\apiclient.py", line 461, in create_job
    self.create_job_description(job)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\runners\dataflow\internal\apiclient.py", line 491, in create_job_description
    job.options, file_copy=self._gcs_file_copy)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\runners\dataflow\internal\dependency.py", line 328, in stage_job_resources
    setup_options.requirements_file, requirements_cache_path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\runners\dataflow\internal\dependency.py", line 262, in _populate_requirements_cache
    processes.check_call(cmd_args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\utils\processes.py", line 44, in check_call
    return subprocess.check_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 186, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Python27\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', 'download', '--dest', 'c:\\users\\james\\appdata\\local\\temp\\dataflow-requirements-cache', '-r', 'requirements.txt', '--no-binary', ':all:']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be that Dataflow is not receiving the file with the extra dependencies of your pipeline. To install them, you'd do this:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Then you'll want to edit the `requirements.txt` file and leave only the packages that were installed from PyPI and are used in your pipeline.

When you run your pipeline, pass the following command-line option:

```
--requirements_file requirements.txt
```

This is documented in the [Apache Beam's Python Pipeline Dependencies docs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Pablo, I made the requirements.txt files and made sure to check all the packages and use the ones only from PyPI and I use in my pipline, although I now get t error which I have put into my question.

Comment: It worked, I did it in the google SDK and no issues, it was the fact that I was using gitbash... thanks!